# Get the table row id on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, row

I have this `<td>` tag:

```
<td align="center">
   <div class="dropdown">
      <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-picture" id=@TableRowId></button>
         <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Show</a>
            <a href="#">Edit</a> 
         </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

And this JavaScript function:

```
function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Image of the Table:

[image: Image of table]

I need to get the specific ID row when click in the picture image to open drop-down menu for that row.

I have an ID iterator: `@TableRowId` that gets the row number.

Comment: Where is the row? And where is the picture?

Comment: I want when the image icon clicked, to open dropdown manu, i need to know the row id for that, otherwise, i every click, the dropdown manu is drop from the first row.

Comment: Check my answer man. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a table and `tr` you can use `parentNode` to retrieve the `tr` id:

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  var id = el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
  console.log(id);
  var all = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-content');
  for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
     all[i].classList.remove('show');
  }
  document.getElementById(id).querySelector('.dropdown-content').classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.dropdown-content{
  display: none;
}
.show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id='id_1'>
    <td align="center">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-picture" id=@TableRowId>Click here</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Show</a>
          <a href="#">Edit</a> 
        </div>
      </div>
  </tr>
  <tr id='id_2'>
    <td align="center">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-picture" id=@TableRowId>Click here</button>
        <div id="myDropdown_2" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Show</a>
          <a href="#">Edit</a> 
        </div>
      </div>
  </tr>
  <tr id='id_3'>
    <td align="center">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction(this)" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-picture" id=@TableRowId>Click here</button>
        <div id="myDropdown_3" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Show</a>
          <a href="#">Edit</a> 
        </div>
      </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think i need that div element: <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"> to dropdown to show

Comment: Check now. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the id to your function in the onclick attribute `onclick="myFunction(this.id)"`. Then change your function definition to include that argument `function myFunction(id) { ...`